# Can we run powershell script via hosted web api in azure?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

want to run powershell scripts from a web API hosted in azure. But I am getting Execution Policy error while trying to import modules and when I try to change the execution policy using below code

ps.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy").AddArgument("Unrestricted")
.AddParameter("Scope", "CurrentUser");
It says Unauthorized access on C:/Powershell.

This works fine in localhost, but not on deployed web api.

Is there a workaround on this or can we not run powershell scritps via hosted api at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can [package your PowerShell Scripts into Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal) and expose them as Web APIs.

This gives you the added advantage of leveraging [bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp) with your functions if required, and other platform benefits of Azure Functions like [auto scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan).